# «Мчитесь вы, будто, как я же, изгнанники»

Tags: сравнительный-оборот, учебное-задание

*Тучки небесные, вечные странники!

Степью лазурною, цепью жемчужною

Мчитесь вы, будто, **как я же**, изгнанники,

с милого севера в сторону южную.*
М. Ю. Лермонтов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем является "как я же" в этом предложении?
Что это за конструкция внутри сравнительного оборота?

Answer (score 3):

Выражение **БУДТО КАК Я ЖЕ** обособляем с двух сторон. После слова **БУДТО** запятой нет:

*Тучки небесные, вечные странники!

Степью лазурною, цепью жемчужною

**Мчитесь вы, будто как я же, изгнанники,**

с милого севера в сторону южную.*

Союз **БУДТО КАК** здесь употреблён как союз **СЛОВНО КАК.**

**СЛОВНО КАК**, **союз**
Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «словно как» выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Между словами «словно» и «как» знак препинания не ставится.

*Взглянули на нее, а она – красная, как сукно алое, и смотрит быстро, **словно как испугалась,** и весело ей.* Н. Лесков, Житие одной бабы.
*Придет, **словно как тучка,** прольется, свежо так, хорошо станет, а что такое было – не поймешь!*
[Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. СЛОВНО КАК](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/654/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)

Первый раз вижу такое странное пунктуационное оформление лермонтовского текста. Я имею в виду запятую после БУДТО.

Comment: Пример такой пунктуации можно встретить в Рабочей тетради №1 к учебнику Э. Э. Кац, Н. Л. Карнаух, Литература. 6 класс. Может, это какая-то адаптированная для детей пунктуация? Хотя, ведь это уже не младшие школьники.

Comment: По всей видимости, "как я же" - конструкция, относимая к "изгнанникам" : смысл не "мчитесь подобно мне", а "мчитесь, будто _вы_ изгнанники, как и я".

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова Очень жаль, что Вы отказались от изображения текста двухсотлетней давности, — красиво! нечасто! убедительно! Поддерживаю с удовольствием.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, благодарю Вас! Хотела добавить иллюстрацию, получилось почему-то два ответа. Удалила второй, а надо было первый. Не мой был день).

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Степью лазурною, цепью жемчужною Мчитесь вы, **будто, как я же, изгнанники**, с милого севера в сторону южную.

Здесь внутри одного сравнительного оборота ***будто изгнанники*** находится другой оборот ***как я же*** со значением ***как и я.***

При перемещении оборота получаем такой вариант: Мчитесь вы, **будто изгнанники, как и я**. **Это правильный смысл.** Союз БУДТО должен относиться к "изгнанникам"

Вариант с объединением оборотов **соответствует интонационному прочтению, но противоречит смыслу**: Мчитесь вы, будто как я же, изгнанники. Получается: Мчитесь вы, подобно мне, изгнанники.

Answer (score 1):

Существуют разные варианты оформления. И обосновать можно каждый…

**Академические издания**, выделяя оборот "будто как я же" запятыми, третью запятую — после слова "изгнанники" — не ставят.

Из собрания сочинений Лермонтова, подготовленного ИРЛИ РАН (Пушкинским Домом) к 200-летию со дня рождения поэта (Собрание сочинений: В 4 т. Т. 1. Стихотворения / Отв. ред. тома Н.Г. Охотин. — СПб, 2014):

*Тучки небесные, вечные странники!

Степью лазурною, цепью жемчужною

**Мчитесь вы, будто как я же, изгнанники**

С милого севера в сторону южную.*

Такую же пунктуацию приводит и [**Национальный корпус русского языка**](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=poetic&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&nodia=1&req=%CC%F7%E8%F2%E5%F1%FC%20%E2%FB%2C%20%E1%F3%E4%F2%EE%20%EA%E0%EA%20%FF%20%E6%E5%2C%20%E8%E7%E3%ED%E0%ED%ED%E8%EA%E8).

Такая же пунктуация имела место и в первой (прижизненной) публикации этого стихотворения Лермонтова:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если убрать оборот, то получится: Мчитесь вы изгнанники с милого севера в сторону южную. И что это за конструкция?  Почему не обособлено приложение, отнесенное к местоимению.

Comment: _Sharon: Если убрать оборот, то получится: Мчитесь вы изгнанники с милого севера в сторону южную._ === Не совсем так. По-моему, получится примерно так: _Мчитесь вы, (запятая!) изгнанники с милого севера в сторону южную..._  Да и оборот зачем убирать?

Comment: Ну, интересуюсь, что это за синтаксис. Изгнанники  - это приложение?

Comment: _Sharon: Ну, интересуюсь, что это за синтаксис. Изгнанники - это приложение?_ === Да.

Comment: Если оно относится к местоимению "вы", то обособляется в обязательном порядке. А запятых нет.

Comment: После слова "изгнанники" стоит определение. Изгнанники (какие?) — С милого севера... Имеет место (при такой пунктуации!) распространённое приложение. Одной запятой (перед приложением) достаточно.

Comment: Ну да, всё правильно, а я-то по наивности полагала, что это тучки мчатся с севера на юг. Тогда это конечно же самое достойное и самое академическое  понимание поэта. Составной сравнительный оборот просто отдыхает.

Comment: Sharon, если бы я был автором текста, я бы, наверное, избрал  другую пунктуацию. Но я не автор... И сейчас просто пытаюсь обосновать допустимой принятой в академических изданиях. Завтра собирался посмотреть, что было в первом издании этого стихотворения Лермонтова.

Comment: Да, интересно. Столько раз читали стихотворение и не замечали разное оформление.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, существуют два варианта оформления. **Какой же верный?**

Вот достаточно новый (2011 год) в серии "Великие поэты: Мчитесь вы, будто, **как я же**, изгнанники...

Вот достаточно старый (1901 год): Мчитесь вы, будто, **как я же**, изгнанники... Текст **исправлен**, хотя более ранний вариант с одним обособлением приложен. [https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Тучи_(Лермонтов)](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8_(%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Вот еще вариант с двумя обособлениями: https://www.stihi.ru/2014/10/07/6755

**Так где же правда?** Может быть, попробовать смысл понять? Уберем оборот ***будто как я же*** и получим:  Мчитесь вы, изгнанники, с милого севера в сторону южную.

А в следующей строфе – опровержение. Никакие они не изгнанники, нет у них Родины, нету изгнания. Поэтому они только **будто изгнанники, как и я**.

Таким образом, союз БУДТО относится к "изгнанникам",  а **не входит в общий сравнительный оборот.**

Поэтому, вероятно, и правится пунктуация, поэтому и существуют варианты, а за правдой надо к хорошим литературоведам обращаться.

**Примечание.** Более всего огорчают ответы, в которых уверенно сообщается о правильной и единственной форме письма: "Выражение БУДТО КАК Я ЖЕ обособляем с двух сторон. После слова БУДТО запятой нет". Варианты отрицаются без малейшего сомнения, а это не очень правильная позиция не только для участника, но и для форума в целом.

Comment: Я бы не стал доверять перепечаткам из Интернета. Они же все друг у друга этот стих копируют и создаётся впечатление, что с запятой печатали часто. В моих двух добротных изданиях (бумажных) нет запятой. Зато есть точка с запятой после "чужды страдания", а по Вашей ссылке на Википедию там точка. Вряд ли есть смысл для каждой ошибки искать причины.

Comment: Допустим, можно придать смысл каждому из вариантов. Разве в таком случае решающим должно быть мнение литературоведов, а не автора?

Comment: Я всего лишь обратила внимание на два варианта оформления. Если они существуют, то было бы неплохо объяснить этот факт. Как это сделать? Можно учитывать академичность изданий, можно взять авторский вариант. Но правила пунктуации в 19 веке, вероятно, могли отличаться от современных. Что касается смысла, то союз БУДТО, как я думаю, должен относиться к "изгнанниками". Что касается интонации, то здесь скорее произносится общий оборот, вот и запятые так расставлены (оборот внутри оборота не произнесешь). Так что проблема есть, уходить от нее не надо, и я хотела бы услышать мнение специалистов.

Comment: *Если они существуют* — вот в этом я вижу проблему. Пока никто не убедился, что они действительно существуют, мы обсуждаем проблему "в Интернете кто-то неправ". У Вас есть бумажная копия или скан-копия с запятой? Где-то вообще сохранилась хоть одна такая копия?

Comment: В прямой доступности на текущий момент у меня только бумажный сборник 2011 года из серии "Великие поэты". Есть еще место, где много книг, и Лермонтов там тоже есть, посмотрю при случае.  Поэтому лично я не Интернет обсуждаю, здесь есть ОБЪЕКТИВНЫЕ причины для разного письма, а именно смысловой и интонационный варианты для постановки знаков препинания.

Comment: Тогда извините, я что-то неправильно понял. Но всё равно посмотрите, пожалуйста, любопытно. А то в Интернете фотокопий книг Лермонтова на удивление мало находится.

Comment: Посмотрю, конечно, мне тоже любопытно. Вот если бы это был прозаический текст, он выглядел бы так: мчитесь вы, будто изгнанники, как и я. В стихотворении второй оборот пришлось поместить внутри первого. Поэтому обособление одного оборота соответствует интонации, но противоречит смыслу. В то же время я не исключаю, что авторский интонационный вариант  считается  у литературоведов основным. (И очень-очень  жаль, что приходится с Вами не соглашаться, да вот только истина дороже).